# How do I know the adt is installed correctly in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, installation, eclipse-adt

I installed adt in eclipse and I gave the address of my sdk in **windows>preferences**.
but the tasks (android sdk, create new android project, create test project, create new xml file) not showing in the toolbar.
am I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, open "About Eclipse", all installed plugins should be displayed there.

[image: Eclipse About screen]

Clicking on the icon should raise a new screen with the installed version of ADT.